# Execute a command asynchronously while redirecting the output to a file in a batch file?

Tags: windows, asynchronous, batch-file, cmd

Let's say in a batch file, I want to execute *myCommand* asynchronously (without waiting for it to finish). And I don't want to execute *myCommand* in a new console window.

At the same time, I want to redirect the output of *myCommand* to output.txt

So in the batch file, if I write

```
START myCommand > output.txt
```

output.txt will be empty and I will see a new window.

If I write

```
myCommand > output.txt
```

then I cannot execute it asynchronously.

Is there any way I can achieve all these three requirements? (asynchronously, no new window, redirect output)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested it fully, but I think this may work:

```
start /b "" myCommand >output.txt
```

I believe both forms work fine - the only difference is if [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) is redirected as well and START fails to launch myCommand.

Redirecting START: both myCommand and START output are redirected to the file.

```
start /b "" myCommand >output.txt >2&1
```

Redirecting myCommand only: Only myCommand output is redirected. Any START error message will appear on the screen. Note, I opted to escape the redirection instead of [using quotes like jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534244/execute-a-command-asynchronously-while-redirecting-the-output-to-a-file-in-a-bat/14535432#14535432).

```
start /b "" myCommand ^>output.txt ^>2^&1
```

Comment: @jeb - I just tested, and myCommand also inherits the std streams from START. I successfully tested both an .exe and a batch file. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You are right, I tested it without `/b` and then the `start` is redirected. I'm supreised that it's changed if `/b` is present

Comment: @jeb - Since the `/b` option shares the same console, it makes sense the command inherits the streams from START. Without the `/b` option, the START is redirected, but the new console gets its own streams.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly like dbenhams answer,  but you need to force the redirection to the new thread, not to the `start` command.

```
start "myTitle" "myCommand > output.txt"
```

Comment: `/b` is needed. Also, `cmd /c ` may be required before `myCommand`, for example `start /b "BackProcess" "cmd /c dir c:\users > 1.log"`

Comment: Indeed `/b` is needed to use it in the same window. `cmd /c` is only needed if the command is one of the internal cmd.exe commands.